# NodeJS - Split the string of two joined paths, to obtain a certain portion of the string (Closed)

Tags: javascript, node.js, split

Say we have a folder path like so...

```
/just/some/folder/location/
```

And a filepath like so...

```
this/way/for/the/file.txt
```

And we merge/join the two paths together to make a fullpath like so...

```js
var folderPath = "/just/some/folder/location"
var filePath = "this/way/for/the/file.txt"

var joinedPath = path.join(folderPath, filePath);
```

How would I be able to cut the `folderPath` from the string, and keep only part of the `filePath` part so I'm left with an output like the example below?

```
way/for/the/file
```

Comment: Why do you want to merge the folderPath if you also want to cut it?

Comment: Because I need to in order to read a file, the function I merge the paths for in order to read a file comes before the function I'm currently having trouble with here, I haven't specified the read function here because it wasn't part of the issue. 

Comment: checkout my answer

Comment: @Morsmalleo What is the value of `path`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already have the individual variables, do don't have to first join and then remove the value of folderPath.

Using `filePath` you could capture from the first occurrence of `/` to before the last occurrence of a `.` using a pattern

```js
const regex = /\/(\S+)\./;
const str = `this/way/for/the/file.txt`;
const m = str.match(regex);

if (m) console.log(m[1]);
```

Comment: Will definitely also take this into consideration, I like regex, so I will try this answer and as well as @Gopi Kumar Kaushik's answer and report back here with the results.

Comment: Yep this is definitely what I was looking for will post the code used shortly

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **@The fourth bird's** answer, I was able to achieve what I wanted, I had to use a different method of joining the paths but it worked beautifully.

Code Below!

```js
var folder = "/just/some/folder/location/"
var file = "this/way/to/the/file.txt"

var regex = /\/(\S+)\./;
var str = (folder, file) // different way of joining the paths
var m = str.match(regex);

var output = folder.split(folder).join(m[1]);

if (m) console.log(output);
```